# ¿Se pueden agregar más de dos excepciones en una sola línea de código?

Tags: python

Tengo una duda con las excepciones en Python. Acá dejo un ejemplo simple:

```
try:
            if name_delete=="S":
                break;
            else:
                del diccionario[name_delete]
        except ValueError:
            print("A introducido un valor erróneo o inexistente.")
```

En este caso, quiero también colocar en la expceción el error KeyError, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

(No le presten atención a la identación, la página me lo coloca así porque estoy utilizando un celular. El programa de por sí funciona, nada más no tiene la excepción cuando se produce un KeyError).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Respuesta

Como se menciona en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) de Python se puede tener una excepción con múltiples tipos de errores.

Para ello es necesario pasar las excepciones al interno de una tupla de la siguiente manera:

```
except (ValueError, KeyError):
    print("A introducido un valor erróneo o inexistente.")
```

#### Información suplementaria

También es posible manejar diferentes tipos de errores por separado cuando es necesario tomar acciones diferentes para cada  tipo de error. Ejemplo:

```
try:
    # Tu código
except ValueError:
    print("Error de tipo ValueError")
except KeyError:
    print("Error de tipo KeyError")
```

He notado que utilizas un print para entregar un mensaje en concreto y me parece bien, pero toma en cuenta que lo más recomendable es imprimir el error que devuelve el `except` ya que este puede contener más detalles acerca del problema, así que te recomendaría hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
try:
    # Tu código
except (ValueError, KeyError) as error:
    print("A introducido un valor erróneo o inexistente.")
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 5):

Dado que dentro de un mismo bloque `try` pueden producirse excepciones de distinto tipo, es posible utilizar varios bloques `except`, cada uno para capturar un tipo distinto de excepción.

Esto se hace especificando a continuación de la sentencia `except` el nombre de la excepción que se pretende capturar. **Un mismo bloque `except` puede atrapar varios tipos de excepciones, lo cual se hace especificando los nombres de la excepciones separados por comas a continuación de la palabra `except`.**

Supongamos que tienes el siguiente código:

```
try:
    if name_delete=="S":
        break;
    else:
        del diccionario[name_delete]
except ValueError:
    print("A introducido un valor erróneo o inexistente.")
except KeyError:
    print("La clave introducida no existe")

  File "Main.py", line 8
    except ValueError, KeyError:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

El problema aquí es que el informe `except` no toma una lista de excepciones que se especifiquen de esta forma. Por el contrario, Python 2.x la sintaxis `except Exception`, `e`, se utiliza para enlazar la excepción al segundo parámetro opcional especificado (en éste caso `e`), con el fin de que esté disponible para una inspección adicional.

La forma correcta de capturar varias excepciones en un informe except, es especificar el primer parámetro como una tupla que contiene todas las excepciones a ser capturadas. Además, para la máxima portabilidad, utiliza la palabra clave as, ya que la sintaxis es apoyada por Python 2 y Python 3:

```
try:
    if name_delete=="S":
        pass;
    else:
        del diccionario[name_delete]
except (ValueError, KeyError):
    print("A introducido un valor erróneo o inexistente.")
```

Es importante destacar que si bien luego de un bloque `try` puede haber varios bloques `except`, se ejecutará, a lo sumo, uno de ellos.

```
try:
    # aquí ponemos el código que puede lanzar excepciones
except IOError:
    # entrará aquí en caso que se haya producido
    # una excepción IOError
except ZeroDivisionError:
    # entrará aquí en caso que se haya producido
    # una excepción ZeroDivisionError
except:
    # entrará aquí en caso que se haya producido
    # una excepción que no corresponda a ninguno
    # de los tipos especificados en los except previos
```

Como se muestra en el ejemplo precedente también es posible utilizar una sentencia `except` sin especificar el tipo de excepción a capturar, en cuyo caso se captura cualquier excepción, sin importar su tipo. Cabe destacar, también, que en caso de utilizar una sentencia `except` sin especificar el tipo, la misma debe ser siempre la última de las sentencias `except`, es decir que el siguiente fragmento de código es incorrecto.

```
try:
    # aquí ponemos el código que puede lanzar excepciones
except:
    # ERROR de sintaxis, esta sentencia no puede estar aquí,
    # sino que debería estar luego del except IOError.
except IOError:
    # Manejo de la excepción de entrada/salida
```

Finalmente, puede ubicarse un bloque `finally` donde se escriben las sentencias de finalización, que son típicamente acciones de limpieza. La particularidad del bloque `finally` es que se ejecuta siempre, haya surgido una excepción o no. Si hay un bloque `except`, no es necesario que esté presente el `finally`, y es posible tener un bloque `try` sólo con `finally`, sin `except`.

Veamos ahora como es que actúa Python al encontrarse con estos bloques. Python comienza a ejecutar las instrucciones que se encuentran dentro de un bloque `try` normalmente. Si durante la ejecución de esas instrucciones se levanta una excepción, Python interrumpe la ejecución en el punto exacto en que surgió la excepción y pasa a la ejecución del bloque `except` correspondiente.

Para ello, Python verifica uno a uno los bloques `except` y si encuentra alguno cuyo tipo haga referencia al tipo de excepción levantada, comienza a ejecutarlo. Sino encuentra ningún bloque del tipo correspondiente pero hay un bloque `except` sin tipo, lo ejecuta. Al terminar de ejecutar el bloque correspondiente, se pasa a la ejecución del bloque `finally`, si se encuentra definido.

Si, por otra parte, no hay problemas durante la ejecución del bloque `try`, se completa la ejecución del bloque, y luego se pasa directamente a la ejecución del bloque `finally` (si es que está definido).

Informacion sacada de [aqui](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/algoritmos-python/capitulo-12/excepciones) y de [aqui](https://www.toptal.com/python/codigo-buggy-python-los-10-errores-mas-comunes-que-cometen-los-desarrolladores-python)

Comment: Excelente información, pero la pregunta en si es si ***es posible tener más de dos excepciones en una línea***, te recomiendo añadir un ejemplo al menos de cómo hacer exactamente eso puesto que si no, no estás respondiendo la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

Una cláusula except puede nombrar múltiples excepciones como una tupla entre paréntesis

ejemplo

```
try:
    //code
except (IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException) as e:
    pass
```

solo para Python 2:

```
try:
    //code
except (IDontLikeYouException, YouAreBeingMeanException), e:
    pass
```